# Compare date Java format problem

Tags: java

Trying to compare some dates in java but can't get the formatting right, where am i going wrong?

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
    Date date1 = null, date2 = null, today = new Date();
date1 = (Date) df.parse(scan.next());

System.out.println(date1);
            System.out.println(today);
if(date1.compareTo(today) < 0){
        date1 = null;
        System.out.println(start + " is not a valid date.. please try again!");
        }

Please enter a start date:
10/04/2011
Mon Jan 10 00:04:00 GMT 2011
Tue Apr 05 22:27:44 BST 2011
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, but take a look at JodaTime.  I know this doesn't answer your question, but JodaTime provides a lot of nifty features to handle dates.

Comment: While JodaTime is nice, isn't is a bit of overkill for a `compareTo(...)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need **MM**, not **mm**

From [the doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

> M     Month in year
>   m     Minute in hour

Answer (score 0):

Change line 1 to be:
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

mm in SimpleDateFormat is the minutes.  MM is the month.  So your input is actaully January 10 2011 at 00:10:00

Check out http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html for abbreviations and javadoc.